# PHP/mySQL count($array[id]) = 1 even though there are 8 elemnts in the table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, count

Here's my code:

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pw = "";

$dbName = "mathgame";
$tblName = "fragen";
// mit mysql db verbinden

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pw, $dbName);
if ($con->connect_error) {
die ("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);}

// Datenanfrage an db

$result = mysqli_query($con, "select id from $tblName");
$array = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo count($array["id"]);
```

Comments are in German, but I think you get what the program does.
So my problem is, that there are 8 "elements" in the fragen table. But when I count the array it returns one. What did I do wrong?

Comment: each record is one associative array..

Comment: You are only counting the one field in the array.

Comment: [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

Comment: Thank a lot guys, especially Rocket for the right command :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`mysqli_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) fetches **a single row** as an array, where each element is a column. You could use [`mysqli_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) to get the number of rows from the current query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "select id from $tblName");
echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Or, better yet, let the database do the heavy lifting for you:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $tblName");
$array = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $array[0];
```